# How to write properly a file-readed string?

Tags: assembly, mips32, mars-simulator

I am looking for a program that reads a file, then in the stored buffer change an specific char for another in all their appearances and then, write the copy of that modified buffer in another file, the program seems to work well but it doesn't write what is desired, this is what I made:

```
.data 
    file: .asciiz "test.txt"
    fout: .asciiz "result.txt"
    buffer: .space 128
    bsize: .word  127
    msg: .asciiz "The program has been written properly"
    char_to: .asciiz "n"
    char_re: .asciiz "p"

#Macro for open a file for reading
.macro open_file_r()
    li $v0, 13 
    la $a0 file 
    li $a1 0 
    li $a2 0 
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0

.end_macro 

.macro read_file()
    li $v0, 14 #Llamada al sistema para leer archivo
    move $a0, $s0
    la $a1, buffer
    lw $a2, bsize #Longitud del buffer 
    syscall
.end_macro 

#Open a file for writing
.macro open_file_w()
    li $v0, 13
    la $a0 fout
    li $a1 1
    li $a2 0
    syscall 
    move $s6, $v0
.end_macro

.macro write_file()
    li   $v0, 15       # system call for write to file
    move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor 
    la   $a1, ($t0)   # address of buffer from which to write
    li   $a2, 127     # hardcoded buffer length
    syscall         # write to file
.end_macro

.macro close_file()
    li $v0, 16
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall 
.end_macro

.macro close_file_W()
    li $v0, 16
    move $a0, $s6
    syscall 
.end_macro  

.macro exit()
    li $v0 10
    syscall
.end_macro

.text
    main: 
        open_file_r() 
        read_file() 
        la $t0 buffer 
        la $t1, char_to  
        la $t2, char_re
        addi $s1, $t1, 0
        addi $s2, $t2, 0 
    loop:
        lbu $t3, 0($t0) 
        addi $t0, $t0, 1 
        beq $t3 $s1 replace 
        beq $t3 $zero end
        bne $t3 $s1 loop 
    replace:
        sb $s2 -1($t0) 
        b loop 
    end:
        close_file()
        open_file_w()
        write_file()
        close_file_W()
        exit()
```

And the output given in a file (which it's warned as damaged) is:

> \00\00\00The program has been written properly.\00n\00p\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00

So, can anyone help me to see what's wrong in the code?

Comment: The most obvious problem is that you don't save the return value of your `read_file` syscall, which should be the length.  (Unless MARS is weird?)  You'll want that for your `write` to know what length to pass.  That's probably better than looking for a zero in the data.

Comment: Also, you left out commas between operands in several instructions like `beq $t3 $s1 replace` ; I didn't think MARS would assemble that.

Comment: @Peter Cordes MARS actually do assemble that kind of expressions, to be sure I put commas in everyone and the result is still the same, so the suggestion is to have the length and then?

Comment: Use the length of your string as an input to your write, instead of writing the whole buffer including the zeros it started with.